# Target class [App\\GraphQl\\Types\\Admin\\CitiesType] does not exist

Tags: laravel, graphql

I am using [graphql](https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel) in laravel project

every thing work fine at localhost but when i deploy to server [namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/) i faced this problime
Target class [App\GraphQl\Types\Admin\CitiesType] does not exist.

"exception": "Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException",

I am using Postman for request to graphql

this is my type

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQl\Types\Admin;

use App\Models\Cities;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Type as GraphQLType;

class CitiesType extends GraphQLType
{
    protected $attributes = [
        "name" => "CityType",
        "description" => "City",
        "model" => Cities::class,
    ];

    public function fields(): array
    {
        return [
            "id" => [
                "type" => Type::int(),
            ],
            "name" => [
                "type" => Type::string(),
            ],
            "google_name" => [
                "type" => Type::string(),
            ],
            "fee" => [
                "type" => Type::string(),
            ],
            "from" => [
                "type" => Type::string(),
            ],
            "to" => [
                "type" => Type::string(),
            ],
            "is_active" => [
                "type" => Type::boolean(),
            ],
        ];
    }
}
?>
```

this is my query

```
<?php
namespace App\GraphQl\Queries\Admin;
use App\Models\Cities;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
class CitiesQuery extends Query{

    protected $attributes = ['name' => 'cities'];

    public function type(): Type 
    { 
        return Type::listOf(GraphQL::type("CityType"));
    }

    public function args(): array{
        return[
            'id' => [
                'name' => 'id',
                'type' => Type::int(),
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function resolve($root, $args){
        
        return Cities::where('is_active','0')->get();
    }
}


?>
```

this is

```
config/graphql.php
```

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);
return [
    'route' => [
        
        'prefix' => 'graphql',
        'controller' => \Rebing\GraphQL\GraphQLController::class . '@query',
        'middleware' => [],
        'group_attributes' => [],
    ],
    'default_schema' => 'default',

    'batching' => [
        'enable' => true,
    ],


    'schemas' => [
        'default' => [
            'query' => [
                'cities' => \App\GraphQl\Queries\Admin\CitiesQuery::class,
            ],
            'mutation' => [
            
            ],
            
            'types' => [
                \App\GraphQl\Types\Admin\CitiesType::class
            ],

           
            'middleware' => null,

           
            'method' => ['GET', 'POST'],

           
            'execution_middleware' => null,
        ],
    ],

    'types' => [
        
        \App\GraphQl\Types\Admin\CitiesType::class

    ],


    'error_formatter' => [\Rebing\GraphQL\GraphQL::class, 'formatError'],


    'errors_handler' => [\Rebing\GraphQL\GraphQL::class, 'handleErrors'],

    'security' => [
        'query_max_complexity' => null,
        'query_max_depth' => null,
        'disable_introspection' => false,
    ],

    'pagination_type' => \Rebing\GraphQL\Support\PaginationType::class,


    'simple_pagination_type' => \Rebing\GraphQL\Support\SimplePaginationType::class,


    'defaultFieldResolver' => null,

    'headers' => [],


    'json_encoding_options' => 0,


    'apq' => [
        
        'enable' => env('GRAPHQL_APQ_ENABLE', false),

        
        'cache_driver' => env('GRAPHQL_APQ_CACHE_DRIVER', config('cache.default')),

        
        'cache_prefix' => config('cache.prefix') . ':graphql.apq',

        
        'cache_ttl' => 300,
    ],

    'execution_middleware' => [
        \Rebing\GraphQL\Support\ExecutionMiddleware\ValidateOperationParamsMiddleware::class,
        \Rebing\GraphQL\Support\ExecutionMiddleware\AutomaticPersistedQueriesMiddleware::class,
        \Rebing\GraphQL\Support\ExecutionMiddleware\AddAuthUserContextValueMiddleware::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: Have you executed `composer install` command?

Comment: Sure dear, I have.